# Bitlocker, eDrive and cloning

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I have an existing Windows 8.1 installation that I want to copy to a Samsung SSD that supports eDrive for hardware accelerated encryption. The machine meets all the requirements.

Is it possible to clone an existing install and then enable Bitlocker with eDrive? Some sources say you need to do a fresh install, but don't explain why. Does the installer do something special?

Comment: Samsung says clean install, no way around it....http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/faqs_03.html

Comment: Nice how to article...http://www.ckode.dk/desktop-machines/how-to-enable-windows-edrive-encryption-for-ssds/

Comment: If you ever have to re-provision the Samsung drive once edrive is enabled you will need the psid revert tool found here....http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2366848 Samsung does not make this available publicly.

Comment: I strongly suggest you stay way from OEM specific encryption solutions.  Using Bitlocker is one thing but hardware OEMs often do not have the best support plan in the world.

Comment: It would be nice to get transparent performance, otherwise Veracrypt is an option.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that sedutil might be easier than Bitlocker, which appears to be a giant pain in the arse. https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/wiki/Encrypting-your-drive